# Define access point for REST API Resource

Tags: rest

I need to define the path for a REST resource: Payments Types

Two options:

1. /paymentstypes
2. /payments/types

What will be the best choice according best practices and semantic?

Im thinking in the CRUD operations and Query operations

Answer (score 1):

REST APIs are usually designed with "collections" of "resources" in mind.

It depends on what exactly you're returning. If you're talking about a collection of `PaymentType` resources, you should use `/paymenttypes` (or perhaps `/payment_types` for readability).

If, on the other hand, you're referring to a subcollection of the `Payment` resource called `Type`, you would generally use something like `/payments/1/types`

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services) for more.